# Discussion Board with Custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a custom list, which will have collection of goals. and i have an discussion board for discuss about those goals from that custom list... so how can i link between those two. what my expectation is, if I click a "discuss" column in the goals custom list then it should be navigate to that current discussion... is it possible? or If you have any new Idea? and i am very new to sharepoint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to create a webpart page and add the custom as well as discussion list web parts to the page.

Then you can pass value from the custom list to the discussion list using the connection setup from the webpart menu.